# Avoid geocoder.geocode in Google maps and use variable to pass to google.maps.Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps api version 3 in one of my projects and it's working properly. 
I use this function to set a marker to point customer address.

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = 'ulitsa "Dimcho Debelyanov" 3, Sofia, Bulgaria';
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            map.setZoom(16);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

But sometimes request to geocoder is not success and marker is not constructed. 
I have tried to hardcode results array into variable (result from results.toSource() ) 
and pass direct into

```
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
```

But this not working properly because .toSource keep only variables. I receive following error: 
`InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`
 I think google.maps.Marker expected object as an argument. 
When I reveal object into debugger I saw that it received several methods from prototype chain:

```
__proto__: Q
b: function (a){return a?Md(this.lat(),a.lat())&&Md(this.lng(),a.lng()):!1}
constructor: function Q(a,b,c){a-=0;b-=0;c||(a=Kd(a,-90,90),180!=b&&(b=Ld(b,-180,180)));this.nb=a;this.ob=b}
equals: function (a){return a?Md(this.lat(),a.lat())&&Md(this.lng(),a.lng()):!1}
lat: function (){return this[a]}
lng: function (){return this[a]}
toString: function (){return"("+this.lat()+", "+this.lng()+")"}
toUrlValue: function (a){a=Sd(a)?a:6;return We(this.lat(),a)+","+We(this.lng(),a)}
__proto__: Object
```

So If i put `lat: function (){return this[a]}` into object this is not be enough. 
The problem is interested. I'm searching ideas how to solve the problem.

I would appreciate any idea and help.

After good answer from Hollister I have rewrite my code to this 
function avoid geocoder entirely (I get latitide and longtitude from geocoder 
response).

```
    function createGoogleMap() {
        var map, latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.67218039999999, 23.354384200000027);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            title: 'улица „Димчо Дебелянов“ 3, 1113 София, България'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', createGoogleMap);
```

May be this help someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. If you already have the location lat & lng, then you don't need the geocoder. If the geocoder *is* available, then there's no issue.

If it's setting a marker when the geocoder is not available, maybe this is a solution.

All the `Marker` needs for its `position` property is a `LatLng` object (which is what the `results[0].geometry.location` object is). You can cache this by address on a successful geocode call, then look it up from there subsequently:

```
var cachedAddresses = {};

function cacheAddress(address, location) {
  cachedAddresses[address] = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
};

function createMarker(location, address) {
    map.setCenter(location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location,
        title: address || location.toString()
    });
    map.setZoom(16);
};

if (cachedAddresses[address]) {
    console.log('getting address from cache');
    createMarker(cachedAddresses[address], address);
} else {
    console.log('geocoding address...');
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            // cache the address for future lookup
            cacheAddress(address, results[0].geometry.location);
            createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, address);
        } else {
            console.log('Geocode failed: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

This can also be persisted by storing the lat & lng values by address and reconstituting the LatLng object for the marker call. A JSON structure like this may work:

```
{address: 'the address':
  {
    lat: 42.6721804,
    lng: 23.3543842
  }
}
```

This would be pretty specific, though. Slight differences in address would miss the cache.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/Z7Q4d/) that demonstrates this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what I need "All the Marker needs for its position property is a LatLng object (which is what the results [0]. Geometry.location object is)."